# What share of the stock market is owned by whom

Tags: equities, market, investment

These days we were discussing whom you have to beat if you are trying to earn money in the stock market. I think the players are

- private stock holders
- actively managed investment funds
- ETFs
- maybe other players whom I don't know

So my question is: What share of e.g. the whole Dow Jones, MSCI World, etc. is owned by these groups? Are there any statistics or estimations?

I am aware that you can also earn money by just buying and holding shares so you will not "really compete" with the others, but this is not part of the question. I am just wondering about the shares of these players.

Comment: the question is somewhat opinion based, since a private investor might own an ETF that owns a stock, so which bucket are you allocating to? It is impossible to know then?

Comment: I would allocate this stock to the ETF basket since I want to know about the competitors. If a private investor owns a part of a fund that owns a stock, the competitor on the market is the fund, not the private person.

Comment: I have seen are some figures on this but they tend either to be out of date, or as Attack68 suggested they involve arbitrary classifications that make them subject to questioning. They all agree that the individual investor is a small part of the market nowadays and institutions (of many different kinds, variously classified) own the great majority of stock.

Comment: You can see an example of available data here from OECD, it divides the owners into Private Corporations, Public Sector, Strategic Individuals, Institutional Investors and Other Free Float. These categories are probably too broad for your purposes. https://crain-platform-cpi-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/2019-10/10.24.2019%20OECD%20Owners-of-the-Worlds-Listed-Companies.pdf